# How to get data within a timeframe out of MongoDB with new PHP mongoDB driver

Tags: php, mongodb

Basically, I want to get all records that have been made today from mongoDB with the new mongoDB driver, I saw a few other questions about this topic, but they didn't help me out, because they're all outdated.

In the database there is a DateTime variable, a 13 character Epoch timestamp (the last 3 characters are for miliseconds). It looks like this:
1465396254347

This is the code I tried.

```
<?php 

//include the export library

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//make connection
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$filter = [];
$optie = [];


$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $optie);
$rows_tasks = $manager->executeQuery("analys.tasks", $query);


echo "<pre>";
foreach($rows_tasks as $row){
//I just took the first row as an example
echo "id                  : ".$row->_id."<br />";
echo "time from mongo hash: ".$row->createdAt->toDateTime()->format(DateTime::ISO8601)."<br />"; //echo's out 2016-06-08T14:30:54+0000
echo "time from mongo     : ".$row->createdAt."<br /><br />"; //echo's out 1465396254347

}
```

I have to tried to do it with Regex
by changing

```
$filter = [];
```

to

```
$filter = ['createdAt' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('1465396254347', 'i')];
```

but even

```
$filter = ['createdAt' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('1', 'i')];
```

gave me nothing...

after that I tried to do

```
$filter = ['createdAt' => array('$gt' => 1)];
$filter = ['createdAt' => array('$gt' => '1')];
$filter = ['createdAt' => ['$gt' => 1]];
$filter = ['createdAt' => ['$gt' => '1']];
```

When I clear out the filter, it shows all my records, but when I try it with any of above showed filters it's blank or an syntax error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So is the field a "date" or a "string" or a "numeric value"? If you think you're confused, then I think your question is more confusing to us. Which type is the actual data you need to match??

Comment: @NeilLunn It's a 13 character Unix epoch timestamp. The question is not about matching this timestamp, but about getting all data after some date (for example, all records of today).

Comment: Show a document as viewed from the [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo). We ask you use this tool because unlike a php dump or some other tool or your own typing it **"actually shows us what the real type is"**. This is information we can rely on and therefore tell you what actual query to use. That is if the process of doing that does not make it self evident to yourself beforehand.

Comment: @NeilLunn
Here is the dump from PHP

http://i.imgur.com/kDd8qKu.png


and here is a screenshot from mongoDB

http://i.imgur.com/otg8UP0.png

Answer (score 0):

Using the [MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php) class should work, as follows:

```
$filter = ['createdAt' => ['$gt'  => new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(1465396254347)]];
```